# IE 8: Cannot Wrap Text from Top around Embed Object (YouTube Video)

Tags: html, css

I have an embedded YouTube video, specified with an "embed" tag. It is followed by text, which wraps around the embedded video.

```
<embed align="left" 
width="420" height="345"
src="https://www.youtube.com/v/WBgwuFM92i4"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</embed>

Some text follows
```

In Firefox, everything looks fine, and the text wraps **from the top** next to the video.

But **in IE 8**, the text starts **from the bottom** next to the video, and there is no wrapping.

I need the text to be at the same top coordinate as the video's top coordinate, and then it can wrap around it.

Comment: Try `style='float:left'` instead of `align="left"`. In case of multiple floats, if you see some weird things, do not forget to use `<div style='clear:both'></div>`

Comment: Thanks, working now.